# Is there anything like ruby's .send in HTMLBars or Handlebars?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

Was wondering if there's anything like ruby's [.send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send) for htmlbars. Been trying to search for it, but can't seem to find a proper answer. Here's what I want to do:

```
{{"name-of-helper" arguments}}
```

As simple as this. Is there any trick under it to achieve this effect?

Comment: What does ruby's `send` do?

Comment: Check my updated question. Basically, you can call functions/methods dynamically if you have their names in a string. Like this: `self.send("name")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in one or supplemented one but if you need it you can [write one for yourself](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/templates/writing-helpers/).

Ember includes ["component" helper](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/composing-components/#toc_code-component-code-helper) which allows you to dynamically build component - it's not exactly the same, but might suit your needs.

Comment: That's not really part of the answer, but I would advise against having logic in your view (especially dynamically calling other helpers) unless really necessary.

Comment: The "component" helper is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!I'm trying to generate forms dynamically from a certain content Object, so the component helper will be kind of needed for that.